# How to change the icon on the window when I run my program in KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

So I have read how to change the ICON on the window, however it seems to not be changing the icon when I run my program using Kivy and Python. Inside my python code there is something like this:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App

Config.window_icon = "Desktop/X.jpg"
```

Lets say my picture is named X.jpg and has that right path. Is there another way to change that icon: The picture is attached to show what Icon I want to change.

I am using Python 2.7.x and Kivy 1.9.1 
Thanks~[image]

Comment: Try setting the Config before importing Window - in general, you must always perform Config changes before anything else, even imports (as these imports may have already read in the old config values).

Comment: There's an outstanding bug for this which may be why you're having issues https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2202

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refering to:

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html

this should do it:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','window_icon','path/to/icon.ico')
```

Answer (score 13):

The previous answer didn't work for me and I found another solution that did, so I wanted to share.

In build you can add:

```
self.icon = 'ico/path.ico'
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation - Application](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html)

> Icon of your application. The icon can be located in the same directory as your main file. You can set this as follows:

```
class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    self.icon = 'myicon.png'
```

> Changed in version 1.8.0: icon is now a StringProperty. Don’t set the icon in the class as previously stated in the documentation.
>
> Note
>
> For Kivy prior to 1.8.0, you need to set this as follows:

```
class MyApp(App):
    icon = 'customicon.png'
```

> Recommended 256x256 or 1024x1024? for GNU/Linux and Mac OSX 32x32 for Windows7 or less. <= 256x256 for windows 8 256x256 does work (on Windows 8 at least), but is scaled down and doesn’t look as good as a 32x32 icon.