# Is it possible to change a Kivy app taskbar icon?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy app, here's the code:

```
class ComicNotificatorApp(App):

    def build(self):

        Window.size = (300, 300)
        self.title = 'Comics Notificator'
        self.icon = 'assets/icon.png'
        return Label(text=to_display)
```

and I'd like to change the taskbar icon of the app

[image: this one here]

and while I'm at it, how can I change the size of the window to automatically fit the size of the label, as opposed to setting it manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666323/how-to-change-the-icon-on-the-window-when-i-run-my-program-in-kivy) <-- this link mention a similar question and I think this may help

[kivy doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html) for your ref about kivy config object

and I only know how to change the window's icon but not the task bar one

```
...

class MyKivyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'window's title'
        self.icon = <icon>: str  <----

...
```

the taskbar one maybe you can change it when packaging

> how can I change the size of the window to automatically fit the size of the label

maybe you can try to use the kivy.config.Config.set() , if I get it correctly , you want to set the size of the window == size of label ? if so then set the size of the label first, then use `kivy.config.Config.set('graphics', 'width', <size>: str)` `kivy.config.Config.set('graphics', 'height', <size>: str)`

```
# I assume you won't change the label size after starting the kivy screen 
import kivy
kivy.config.Config.set('graphics', 'width', <label_width>: str)
kivy.config.Config.set('graphics', 'width', <label_height>: str)

...
```

because the config have to set at the very beginning , before the kivy window is created
e.g.

```
import kivy
# set config here
# import another stuff
```

hope this help  : )

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for your main question `Is it possible to change a kivy app taskbar icon`, no it isn't possible to change the taskbar icon *if you are running the app as a script, not an executable of some kind*. However, the taskbar icon will automatically sync with your window icon when run as an executable(by packaging your app using pyinstaller or py2exe, anything like that could work)