# How to set an icon in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to set my own icon in my kivy app, but its not working. I have tried both with icon.ico and icon.png.

This is what i have tried:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'myicon.png'
```

and:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','window_icon','icon.ico')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'icon'? Where do you want the image to be displayed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666323/how-to-change-the-icon-on-the-window-when-i-run-my-program-in-kivy If you look at this question, you will see a image of where i want the icon. (There is no icon on mac by the way, so i am using Windows)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does the logo not show or an error pops up?

Comment: There's an outstanding bug for this which may be why you're having issues github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your icon path needs to be either absolute or relative to your application file. So if your directory structure looks like this:

```
my_app/
├── app.py
└── things
    └── images
        └── my_icon.png
```

Then you're going to need

```
class MyApp:
    def build(self):
        self.icon = r'C:\Users\you\path\to\my_app\things\images\my_icon.png'
```

Obviously you'll want to replace that with the actual path. You should also be able to have

```
        self.icon = r'things\images\my_icon.png'
```

but I'm not sure about that.